# Magnitude of electromagnetic four-vector potential

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

For any four vector $V^\mu$, its magnitude $V^\mu V_\mu$ is a Lorentz scalar.

For example, the energy-momentum of a particle, we find $p^\mu p_\mu = m^2$, the rest mass. For the four-current $J^\mu J_\mu = \rho_0^2$, the "proper" charge density.

So what in the world is the scalar obtained from the electromagnetic four-potential: $A^\mu A_\mu$ ?

Comment: It's not a very interesting quantity, because it's not gauge invariant.

Comment: Regardless, it is a Lorentz scalar. Even if you do not find it interesting, I'm still curious about it.  Once the field is specified in any coordinate system, the value is fixed in all coordinate systems. Consider in such a case, where the gauge is fixed.

Comment: "Not interesting" means that it probably doesn't have any physical interpretation, since it's not a physical quantity. There might be one I'm not aware of, though.